# Problems with Traefik/Keycloak (and Gatekeeper) in front of Kibana

Tags: authentication, kibana, keycloak

I want to use Keycloak as a standard way of authenticating users to applications running in our Kubernetes clusters. One of the clusters is running the Elastic ECK component (v1.1.1) and we use the operator to deploy Elastic clusters and Kibana as a frontend. In order to keep things as simple as possible I’ve done the following.

**Deployed Kibana**

```
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.kibana.name }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/service.sticky.cookie: "true"
spec:
  version: {{ .Values.kibana.version }}
  count: {{ .Values.kibana.instances }}
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: {{ .Values.kibana.elasticCluster }}
    namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  podTemplate:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana
        env:
        - name: SERVER_BASEPATH
          value: {{ .Values.kibana.serverBasePath }}
        resources:
          requests:
            {{- if not .Values.kibana.cpu.enableBurstableQoS }}
            cpu: {{ .Values.kibana.cpu.requests }}
            {{- end }}
            memory: {{ .Values.kibana.memory.requests }}Gi
          limits:
            {{- if not .Values.kibana.cpu.enableBurstableQoS }}
            cpu: {{ .Values.kibana.cpu.limits }}
            {{- end }}
            memory: {{ .Values.kibana.memory.limits }}Gi
  http:
    tls:
      selfSignedCertificate:
        disabled: true
```

**Created Ingress**

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: kibana-{{ .Values.kibana.name }}-stripprefix
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  stripPrefix:
    prefixes: 
      - {{ .Values.kibana.serverBasePath }}
    forceSlash: true

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.kibana.name }}-ingress
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: http
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: {{ .Release.Namespace }}-kibana-{{ .Values.kibana.name }}-stripprefix@kubernetescrd
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: {{ .Values.kibana.serverBasePath }}
        backend:
            servicePort: {{ .Values.kibana.port }}
            serviceName: {{ .Values.kibana.name }}-kb-http
```

**Result**
Deploying the above works perfectly fine. I’m able to reach the Kibana UI using the external IP exposed by our MetalLB component. I simply enter http://external IP/service/logging/kibana and I’m presented to the Kibana log in screen and I can log on using the “built in” authentication process.

**Adding the Keycloak Gatekeeper**
Now, if I add the following to the Kibana manifest, effectively adding the Keycloak Gatekeeper sidecar to the Kibana Pod:

```
  - name: {{ .Values.kibana.name }}-gatekeeper
    image: "{{ .Values.kibana.keycloak.gatekeeper.repository }}/docker-r/keycloak/keycloak-gatekeeper:{{ .Values.kibana.keycloak.gatekeeper.version }}"
    args:
      - --config=/etc/keycloak-gatekeeper.conf
    ports:
      - containerPort: 3000
        name: proxyport
    volumeMounts:
    - name: gatekeeper-config
      mountPath: /etc/keycloak-gatekeeper.conf
      subPath: keycloak-gatekeeper.conf
  volumes:
    - name: gatekeeper-config
      configMap:
        name: {{ .Release.Name }}-gatekeeper-config
```

with the following ConfigMap which is "mounted":

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-gatekeeper-config 
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
data: 
  keycloak-gatekeeper.conf: |+
    redirection-url: {{ .Values.kibana.keycloak.gatekeeper.redirectionUrl }}
    discovery-url: https://.../auth/realms/{{ .Values.kibana.keycloak.gatekeeper.realm }}
    skip-openid-provider-tls-verify: true
    client-id: kibana
    client-secret: {{ .Values.kibana.keycloak.gatekeeper.clientSecret }}
    enable-refresh-tokens: true
    encryption-key: ...
    listen: :3000
    tls-cert:
    tls-private-key:
    secure-cookie: false
    upstream-url: {{ .Values.kibana.keycloak.gatekeeper.upstreamUrl }}
    resources:
    - uri: /*
    groups:
    - kibana
```

The upstream-url points to http://127.0.0.1:5601

and add an intermediary service:
In order to explicitly address the Gatekeeper proxy I added another service, “keycloak-proxy” as such:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.kibana.name }}-keycloak-proxy
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    common.k8s.elastic.co/type: kibana
    kibana.k8s.elastic.co/name: cap-logging
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8888
      targetPort: proxyport
```

and change the backend definition in the Kibana definition to:

```
servicePort: 8888
serviceName: {{ .Values.kibana.name }}-keycloak-proxy
```

and then issue the same URL as above, http://external IP/service/logging/kibana, I’m redirected to http://external IP/oauth/authorize?state=0db97b79-b980-4cdc-adbe-707a5e37df1b and get an “404 Page not found” error.

If I reconfigure the “keycloak-proxy” service and convert it into a NodePort and expose it on, say, port 32767 and issue an http://host IP:32767 I’m presented to the Keycloak login screen on the Keycloak server!

If I look into the Gatekeeper startup log I find the following:

```
1.6018108005048046e+09 info starting the service {"prog": "keycloak-gatekeeper", "author": "Keycloak", "version": "7.0.0 (git+sha: f66e137, built: 03-09-2019)"}
1.6018108005051787e+09 info attempting to retrieve configuration discovery url {"url": "https://.../auth/realms/...", "timeout": "30s"}
1.601810800537417e+09 info successfully retrieved openid configuration from the discovery
1.6018108005392597e+09 info enabled reverse proxy mode, upstream url {"url": "http://127.0.0.1:5601"}
1.6018108005393562e+09 info using session cookies only for access and refresh tokens
1.6018108005393682e+09 info protecting resource {"resource": "uri: /*, methods: DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT,TRACE, required: authentication only"}
1.6018108005398147e+09 info keycloak proxy service starting {"interface": ":3000"}
```

This is what I get when I try to access Kibana through the Gatekeeper proxy:

```
http://host/service/logging/kibana (gets redirected to) http://host/oauth/authorize?state=4dbde9e7-674c-4593-83f2-a8e5ba7cf6b5
```

and the Gatekeeper log:

```
1.601810963344485e+09 error no session found in request, redirecting for authorization {"error": "authentication session not found"}
```

I've been struggling with this for some time now and seems to be stuck! If anybody here "knows what's going on" I'd be very grateful.